# Multithreading. How to process a vector in multiple threads while the vector is being filled by another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I need to get info with API requests (3 seconds each) and process received data (tens of seconds).

The current implementation parallelizes the whole task: I know the number of API requests (let's say M), so I create N threads, each of them ~M/N times makes sequentially API request, waits server response, waits, waits,.. receives data, makes some slow computations. I would like to make API requests while processing data. I feel that I need LIFO) Give me, please, some directions, definitions to search and read about, maybe pattern, pseudocode or even code)) Multithreading is not my forte, but I know some basics and want to get deeper knowledge.
I use Visual Studio 2019, C++17.

Simplified current implementation:

```
void TaskForOneThread(const int _PageFrom, const int _PageTo)
{
  for (int i = _PageFrom; i < _PageTo; ++i)
  {
    const Json = MakeRequestAndParse(i); // slow
    Calc(Json);                          // very slow
    // I think it could be speed up with calling MakeRequestAndParse() while Calc()
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsCount; i++)
{
  Threads[i] = std::thread(
      TaskForOneThread,
      PageBegin,
      PageEnd,
    );

  PageBegin  = PageEnd;
  PageEnd   += std::min(Block, PagesCount - PageBegin);
}
```

Comment: Don't use a thread per request sent to a server.  Instead, send all the requests from a single thread, either on a single connection or with multiple connections and multiplexed I/O (like WaitForMultipleObjects).

Comment: Due to the _"slow"_ and _"very slow"_; this suggests a thread pool with work-queue approach.

Comment: Quite honestly, you might do better trying to figure out why your code is so slow.  Visual Studio has an excellent profiler and has identified a number of bottlenecks in my own code.  Finding them is often harder than fixing them.

Comment: If your program is *latency*-bound, then you should use asynchronous IO features of your OS (there is no standard portable API in C++ yet). Otherwise, multithreading is the way to go (assuming the operation can be parallelized). A simple (naive) way to know that is to check the CPU usage of the target core: if it is low, then you are likely latency-bound.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. Special thanks to @RichardCritten. Will dig in this direction)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. First of all because you do not distinguish between "being slow because CPU is a limiting factor" and "being slow because waiting for some external independent event (like bytes finally arrived to a network interface, physically) or hard drive replied with an array of bytes read". These two are fundamentally different and known as "CPU-bound" and "IO-bound" workflows respectively.

Asking someone's else API for data is definitely an IO-bound workflow. It is slow because of the way Internet works. So you need it to be an async non-blocking call. If that does not make sense, then Google it. Three different API calls are to be done in parallel (again, due to parallel nature of the Internet it works perfect) and processed in the "as soon as possible" way.

The next step - the processing - may or may not be slow because it reaches the hardware limitation. Most probable one - CPU (mis)performance. No single reason exist why it may be the case, so it is worthy to profile and carefully study. Thus you get insight into what's happening inside and be able to speed it up or you would realize that you can't actually improve it and then it would make sense to physically parallelize the processing among different CPUs. At this point multithreading - rather than in some sense simpler async - emerges.

The other (and the last) possible outcome is that CPU is not an issue at all. It very well may be slow due to another sort of "waiting" - i.e. another sort of IO. In that case, again, async is your best friend.